# WP Enhanced Media Library Plugin - How to filter by media category in query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a widget that displays images based on the image category of media (I'm using the "Enhanced Media Library" plugin to organize my media).

I just want to retrieve any images in my library under the "Partners" image category. The slug for this category is simply "partners".

I'm not sure how to write the correct query for getting these images. Here is the query that I am using right now:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'Partners',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'partners' 
            )
        )
    );


    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_ID() );
    echo "<img src='" . $image[0] . "'>";

  endwhile;
```

But this does not result in any images being echoed out, despite the fact that there are three images in the "Partners" image category. I believe the query is to blame. I can get all the images to echo out there using a query without a filter. So how do I write the correct query for just the Partners?

Comment: taxonomy is the name of the registered taxonomy, not the term. I think EML's is media_category, but you should check their documentation.

Comment: @Christina - Thanks so much! I simply swapped out the taxonomy name to 'media_category' and it did exactly what it was supposed to do. I swear I looked all over the documentation but I couldn't find the taxonomy anywhere. Please put this as the answer so I can check it off. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think EML's is `media_category`, but you should check their documentation. Documentation in some cases is just opening up the plugin and looking for the registration of the taxonomy, but you can also just hover over the taxonomy in the admin and the url should be something like:

```
.../wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=registered_taxonomy&post_type=register_post_type
```